# Error while importing LDIF

Tags: ldap, apacheds, ldif

**Server:** Apache DS 2.0
**Client:** Apache Directory Studio 2.0

**The problem:** I am running into error while importing a LDIF
This one **works** http://pastebin.com/DKZ4fT0U
This one **does not** http://pastebin.com/Z5NxUxX4

**Error message:** #**!ERROR [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 81     Add Request : Entry**     dn[n]: dc=example,dc=zzz     objectClass: dcObject     objectClass: organization     description: My wonderful company as much text as you want to place in this line up to 32K continuation data for the line above must have <CR> or <CR><LF> i.e. ENTER works on both Windows and *nix system - new line MUST begin with ONE SPACE     dc: example     o: Example, Inc. : **ERR_268 Cannot find a partition** for dc=example,dc=zzz]

The **difference** between the one that works and the one that doesn't work is - I replaced "com" with "zzz"
**Note:** I did delete the previous entry before importing the new LDIF

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server should have a partition dc=example,dc=zzz configured first, otherwise server will reject any entry with the above suffix.